# toggle QMainWindow WindowStaysOnTopHint flag pyside

Tags: python, pyside, qmainwindow

Why, when I toggle the QMainWindow's SetWindowFlags to WindowStaysOnTopHint, does my window disappear, and more importantly not stay on top? I'm using PySide and a QMainWindow.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Browser(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Browser, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(200, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Assets')
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.mi_stay_on_top = QtGui.QAction('Stay On Top', self)
        self.mi_stay_on_top.setShortcut('Ctrl+T')
        self.mi_stay_on_top.setCheckable(True)
        self.mi_stay_on_top.triggered.connect(self.toggle_stay_on_top)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(self.mi_stay_on_top)

        grid = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        grid.setContentsMargins(10,10,10,10)
        self.setLayout(grid)

    def toggle_stay_on_top(self):
        if self.mi_stay_on_top.isChecked():
            # enabled
            self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        else:
            # disable
            self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Browser()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setWindowFlags` method resets the parent, which hides the window.

So you need to do this:

```
def toggle_stay_on_top(self):
    if self.mi_stay_on_top.isChecked():
        # enabled
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    else:
        # disable
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    # re-show the window after changing flags
    self.show()
```

Comment: awesome, i figured and hoped it was something simple i was overlooking. thanks